# Error while including .inc files in php

Tags: php, apache, file, include, wamp

I am trying to include an inc extension file in my php code. But it's rendered as plain text and doesn't get parsed. Below are my php code and inc file.

inc file :

```
class Stack {

    private $stk = array();

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function push($data) {
        array_push($this->stk, $data);
    }

    public function pop() {
        return array_pop($this->stk);
    }
    public function is_empty()
    {
     return empty($this->stk);
    }
}
```

php code :

```
<?php
include('Stack.inc'); 
$s = new Stack();
  $a = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
  foreach ($a as $val){
    $s->push($val);
  }

  while (!$s->is_empty()){
    echo "popping: {$s->pop()}\n";
  }
?>
```

I am using wamp server for php. I changed my httpd.conf file to include

```
<FilesMatch "\.inc$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: So the inc files dont't have the `<?php ... ?>` bracket?

Comment: If you `include` it, PHP will already assume it's PHP, so you can remove that `FilesMatch` thing (although it is recommended to just use `.php`, also for includes). The problem is, is that any PHP code in a PHP file _must_ start with `<?php`, otherwise it dumps you to output mode, which would indeed result in your code showing.

Comment: It has <?php ?> in inc file. I just pasted the text inside the tags. I tried including AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .inc in .htaccess file but of no luck.

Comment: Once again, php will interpret it as php if you `include` it. The `AddHandler` is not needed for that. Simply put: if I add the `<?php` in that `Stack.inc`, it works. So there must be an error somewhere there...